# Renaming a key in mutiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file with multiple dictionaries, one in each line.
They all have the same keys. I want to rename one key from 'id' to 'orderid' in all of them. What is the most efficient way to do so?

Sample data:

```
{'total_ex_tax': '11.0000', 'is_deleted': False, 'status_id': 5, 'id': 614534}
{'total_ex_tax': '100.0000', 'is_deleted': False, 'status_id': 5, 'id': 614535}
```

Code so far:

```
def popAndMergeDicts(dicts):

    dictLine = ast.literal_eval(dicts)
    tempDict = dictLine['billing_address']
    del dictLine['billing_address']
    for i in tempDict:
        dictLine[i] = tempDict[i]
    # insertOrdersInDatabase(dictLine)
    rename_id(dictLine)
    return dictLine


def rename_id(dictionary):

    pass


def process_orders_file(filename):

    lines = tuple(open(filename))
    for line in lines[0:]:
        popAndMergeDicts(line)

process_orders_file('allOrdersData')
```

Comment: Do you want to edit the literal text in the file?  Or do you want to change the name dynamically at runtime?  If so, why?

Comment: Your text editor probably has a find and replace function, or you could change it at runtime, print to a file, then copy paste

Comment: Is this json by any chance?

Comment: Yes. But Python detect it as a dictionary. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename a dictionary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475384/rename-a-dictionary-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trivial:

```
def rename_id(dictionary):
    try:
        dictionary['new_key'] = dictionary.pop('old_key')
    except KeyError:
        # 'old_key' is not present in dictionary.
        if not dictionary.has_key('new_key'):
            raise KeyError('This dictionary is missing "old_key": %s' % 
                           dictionary)
```

If `KeyError` is raised, search your file for the error-causing dictionary and correct it as necessary.

Comment: he needs to edit the question.  the question asks for code for `rename_id`.  why else is the code in the question provided at all?

Comment: Sorry both of you, I think I said the wrong thing. I actually want to change at runtime, I thought you meant something else. My bad.

Comment: getting this:   dictionary['orderid'] = dictionary.pop('id')
KeyError: 'id'

Comment: that means your dictionary does not have a key `id`. check the update to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to use the new dict directly, if not then:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip().replace("id", "orderid"))
```

If you want to use it as dict, then you can try:

```
import ast
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        mydict = ast.literal_eval(line.strip())
        mydict["ordeid"] = mydict.pop("id")
        # use mydict
```

Comment: Wouldn't this replace any occurence of the word id, not just those specific ones?