# Cannot rename Python dict key values with pop - Bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I cannot rename the Python dict using pop as described below. I've used suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475384/rename-a-dictionary-key). Is this a Python bug? I'm using Python 3.5.2

```
>>> d = {'a': 'ABC', 'b': 'CDE', 'c': 'KRT'}
>>> for old_key in d.keys():
        d['NEW_KEY_' + old_key] = d.pop(old_key)
>>> d

{'NEW_KEY_NEW_KEY_NEW_KEY_b': 'CDE', 'NEW_KEY_NEW_KEY_a': 'ABC', 'c': 'KRT'}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you think is buggy behaviour here?

Comment: @roganjosh presumabley the fact that `'NEW_KEY_NEW_KEY_NEW_KEY_b'` exists as does `'c'`

Comment: @FHTMitchell You're probably right. It's still not buggy, it's just more fuel for the argument of not changing something while iterating over it :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm unable to reproduce this in a Docker `python:3.5.2` container (it is reproable in `3.4.9`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, you have to change `for old_key in d.keys()` into `for old_key in list(d.keys())`. That should work because you are iterating over a dynamic entity.

Comment: This needs a bit more explanation IMO. How `dict.keys()` is a view and why you shouldn't mutate something you are iterating over.

Comment: You are welcome to update the answer. Ironically, the code posted in the question works for me already ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's mentioned in the documentation that changing a dictionary while iterating over it might fail to produce correct results. You'd better write something like

```
new_dict = {'NEW_KEY_' + key: value for key, value in old_dict.items()}
```

Comment: This would be better, yes, unless the OP actually does need to modify the original dictionary in-place.

Comment: @AKX: in that case, he can just replace it. `old_dict = {...}`

Comment: No, that just assigns a new value to the name `old_dict`. It's not the same as mutating the original dictionary.

Comment: Nice solution as well. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing your keys as you iterate over a view of them. That's not recommended.

Instead, you can take a copy of your keys and iterate over them. Since dictionary keys are unique, you can use `list` or `set`:

```
d = {'a': 'ABC', 'b': 'CDE', 'c': 'KRT'}

for old_key in list(d):
    d['NEW_KEY_' + old_key] = d.pop(old_key)

# {'NEW_KEY_a': 'ABC', 'NEW_KEY_b': 'CDE', 'NEW_KEY_c': 'KRT'}
```

You can, of course, use a dictionary comprehension, which you should find more efficient.

Comment: @roganjosh, Don't see why not. Do you see a problem with this? The important thing is you aren't iterating over a view.

Comment: So the dictionary comprehension is the *recommended* method. But not everyone is comfortable with them. Where performance isn't a concern a regular `for` loop with `pop` is entirely fine.