# Change the key of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have the below dict

```
dict = {'tma_prot_{}.grnh':[r'$T_n-P_h$'], 'tma_prot_{}.groh':[r'$T_o-P_h$'], 'tma_urea_{}.grcn':[r'$T_c-U_n$'],
        'tma_urea_{}.gron':[r'$T_o-U_n$'], 'tma_wat_{}.grco':[r'$T_c-W_o$']}
```

So instead of `tma_prot_0.grnh` I want 0 to be changed to any number eg: `tma_prot_2.grnh`

this value I get from say `l1 = [0, 2, 11]`

so when I call

```
dict["tma_prot_11.grnh"] or dict["tma_prot_2.grnh"]
```

I should get value of `tma_prot_0.grnh` which is

```
[r'$T_n-P_h$']
```

I want a generalized dictionary.

My attempt

```
for i in l1:
    for key in dict.keys():
        dict["key".format(l1[i])] = dict["key"]
```

Comment: Could you be more clear with your explaination? @WhySoSerious

Comment: Do you have some code which you have attempted?

Comment: Do you have any control over the creation of `dict`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename a dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475384/rename-a-dictionary-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a new dict to store the instanced content:

```py
template_dict = {'tma_prot_{}.grnh':[r'$T_n-P_h$'], 'tma_prot_{}.groh':[r'$T_o-P_h$'], 'tma_urea_{}.grcn':[r'$T_c-U_n$'],
        'tma_urea_{}.gron':[r'$T_o-U_n$'], 'tma_wat_{}.grco':[r'$T_c-W_o$']}

dict = {}
l1 = [0, 2, 11]

for i in l1:
    for key in template_dict:
        dict[key.format(i)] = template_dict[key]
```

Then you can use the `dict` to handle your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

No straightforward way to achieve this. Other answers attempt to rename the keys or add new keys.

My solution seems more complex, but it is quite simple.
It creates a custom dict that modifies the key that it gets rather than the dictionary keys.

```
import re
from collections import UserDict

class MyDict(UserDict):
    digit_regex = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        new_key = self.digit_regex.sub('0', item)
        return super().__getitem__(new_key)

d = MyDict({'tma_prot_0.grnh': [r'$T_n-P_h$'], 'tma_prot_0.groh': [r'$T_o-P_h$'],
            'tma_urea_0.grcn': [r'$T_c-U_n$'], 'tma_urea_0.gron': [r'$T_o-U_n$'],
            'tma_wat_0.grco': [r'$T_c-W_o$']})

for i in [0, 2, 11]:
    print(d['tma_prot_{}.grnh'.format(i)])
```

Outputs

```
['$T_n-P_h$']
['$T_n-P_h$']
['$T_n-P_h$']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```py
for i in l1:
    for key in list(dict.keys()):
        dict[key.format(i)] = dict[key]
```

Comment: this gives `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: Adjusted the answer, the error should have gone away. (Background: in Python3 `dict.keys()` gives an iterator and does not evaluate. You can force it by requesting a `list`.)

Comment: @WhySoSerious In the above code there is no list element access operation, so it can not produce a «list index out of range» error. Either the error comes from a differen part of your code or your comment relates to another answer but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just adding a key, value pair to your dictionary for every number you need?
For example:

```
value = dict["tma_prot_0.grnh"]
for number in l1:
    new_key = "tma_prot_{}.grnh".format(str(number))
    dict[new_key] = value
```

When I get you right you want to have the value available for every number in l1 but either way you can access it for only one number per entry regardless of how you named the key