# Renaming key and sub key in python nested dictionary with iterations

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to rename the key and subkey in python nested dictionary. However, I haven't got the result that I expected yet. Below is the original nested key that I have.

```
nested_dict = {
 0: {0: 33.97, 1: 55.32, 2: 57.31, 3: 71.56},
 1: {0: 27.31, 1: 23.32, 2: 32.25, 3: 60.21},
 2: {0: 65.38, 1: 36.88, 2: 70.88, 3: 21.93},
 3: {0: 35.44, 1: 21.21, 2: 40.72, 3: 51.35}
 }
```

I am trying to change the key and subkey to another value into this.

```
 nested_dict = {
 4: {4: 33.97, 5: 55.32, 6: 57.31, 7: 71.56},
 5: {4: 27.31, 5: 23.32, 6: 32.25, 7: 60.21},
 6: {4: 65.38, 5: 36.88, 6: 70.88, 7: 21.93},
 7: {4: 35.44, 5: 21.21, 6: 40.72, 7: 51.35}
 }
```

What I have in mind is renaming the key using a list. I have tried to replace the key and subkey with a list below:

```
new_key = []
for i in range(4,8):
    new_key.append(i)
```

However, I still haven't got it. Another idea is using pandas DataFrame to rename both key and subkey. I am not sure whether using lists or pandas is suitable for the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code for renaming a key from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475384/rename-a-dictionary-key):

```
mydict[new_key] = mydict.pop(old_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a (nested) *dict comprehension* ([[Python]: PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274)). Note that it generates a **new** dictionary (but you can assign it to the old variable):

> ```py
> >>> from pprint import pprint as pp
> >>>
> >>> nested_dict = {
> ...  0: {0: 33.97, 1: 55.32, 2: 57.31, 3: 71.56},
> ...  1: {0: 27.31, 1: 23.32, 2: 32.25, 3: 60.21},
> ...  2: {0: 65.38, 1: 36.88, 2: 70.88, 3: 21.93},
> ...  3: {0: 35.44, 1: 21.21, 2: 40.72, 3: 51.35}
> ...  }
> >>>
> >>> pp(nested_dict)
> {0: {0: 33.97, 1: 55.32, 2: 57.31, 3: 71.56},
>  1: {0: 27.31, 1: 23.32, 2: 32.25, 3: 60.21},
>  2: {0: 65.38, 1: 36.88, 2: 70.88, 3: 21.93},
>  3: {0: 35.44, 1: 21.21, 2: 40.72, 3: 51.35}}
> >>>
> >>> modified_nested_dict = {k0 + 4: {k1 + 4: v1 for k1, v1 in v0.items()} for k0, v0 in nested_dict.items()}
> >>>
> >>> pp(modified_nested_dict)
> {4: {4: 33.97, 5: 55.32, 6: 57.31, 7: 71.56},
>  5: {4: 27.31, 5: 23.32, 6: 32.25, 7: 60.21},
>  6: {4: 65.38, 5: 36.88, 6: 70.88, 7: 21.93},
>  7: {4: 35.44, 5: 21.21, 6: 40.72, 7: 51.35}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas Dataframe for the desired task, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
nested_dict = {
            0: {0: 33.97, 1: 55.32, 2: 57.31, 3: 71.56},
            1: {0: 27.31, 1: 23.32, 2: 32.25, 3: 60.21},
            2: {0: 65.38, 1: 36.88, 2: 70.88, 3: 21.93},
            3: {0: 35.44, 1: 21.21, 2: 40.72, 3: 51.35}
            }
print("Dictionary before renaming: ", nested_dict)

# Convert nested dictionary to Pandas Dataframe
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nested_dict)

new_keys = list(range(4, 8)) # List of new keys
my_dataframe.columns = new_keys # Set columns to the new keys
my_dataframe.set_index([new_keys], inplace=True) # Set index to the new keys
nested_dict = my_dataframe.to_dict() # Convert back to nested dictionary

print("Dictionary after  renaming: ", nested_dict)
```

This gives you the following expected output:

```
Dictionary before renaming:  {0: {0: 33.97, 1: 55.32, 2: 57.31, 3: 71.56}, 1: {0: 27.31, 1: 23.32, 2: 32.25, 3: 60.21}, 2: {0: 65.38, 1: 36.88, 2: 70.88, 3: 21.93}, 3: {0: 35.44, 1: 21.21, 2: 40.72, 3: 51.35}}
Dictionary after  renaming:  {4: {4: 33.97, 5: 55.32, 6: 57.31, 7: 71.56}, 5: {4: 27.31, 5: 23.32, 6: 32.25, 7: 60.21}, 6: {4: 65.38, 5: 36.88, 6: 70.88, 7: 21.93}, 7: {4: 35.44, 5: 21.21, 6: 40.72, 7: 51.35}}
```