# How to change the name of key in dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

```py
dict_values(
[{'2020-01-01': 6756.5667752718,
  '2020-02-01': 6977.2782868586,
  '2020-03-01': 8345.9643411143,
  '2020-04-01': 10279.6946142039,
  '2020-05-01': 950.3290972804},
 {'2020-01-01': 807.2855755452,
  '2020-02-01': 807.2872293898,
  '2020-03-01': 1006.1969492287,
  '2020-04-01': 1006.262393842,
  '2020-05-01': 151.882531899}])
```

I want to change the values of key, example INPUT '2020-01-01': 6756.5667752718 ... OUTPUT = 'JAN' : 6756.5667752718
I have a function which converts the date

so I've to rename the keys using below function.

```
MONTHS = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 
'JUN','JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
def date_convert(s):
    y = s[:4]
    m = int(s[5:-3])
    d = s[8:]
    month_name = MONTHS[m-1]
    result= month_name
    return result
s = '2020-06-24'
r = date_convert(s)
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the properly formatted code, do not use comments.

Comment: Generally you can't rename a dictionary key. You must add a new key with the same value and remove the old key.

Comment: it's just a function which take input as 2020-05-01 and return MAY. Same function I need to apply while changing the key name in dict.

Comment: Yes, I agree removing the key and adding new key.

Comment: this `m = int(s[5:-3])` is better be written as `m = int( s.split('-')[1] )`, because you never know....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475384/rename-a-dictionary-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is where you want to use the .pop() function, which is a method for removing items from a container, but also returns the removed item in case you wanted to do something with it.

```
MONTHS = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY','JUN','JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
def date_convert(s):
    y = s[:4]
    m = int(s[5:-3])
    d = s[8:]
    month_name = MONTHS[m-1]
    result= month_name
    return result

d = {'2020-01-01': 6756.5667752718, '2020-02-01': 6977.2782868586, '2020-03-01': 8345.9643411143, '2020-04-01': 10279.6946142039, '2020-05-01': 950.3290972804}

for key in list(d):
    value      = d.pop(key)
    new_key    = date_convert(key)
    d[new_key] = value
```