# Rename the keys in a dictionary efficiently

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the form 
`{0: -1.0, 21: 2.23, 7: 7.1, 46: -12.0}`.

How can I turn this into 
`{'p0': -1.0, 'p21': 2.23, 'p7': 7.1, 'p46': -12.0}`

efficiently i.e:

without a for loop and something like `dict[key[i]] = dict.pop("p"+str(key[i]))`?

Comment: Do you want to modify the existing dictionary (e.g. if you have various references to it), or is it sufficient to construct a new dictionary?

Comment: No reply yet to this question so I posted a reply on this assumption.

Comment: The most efficient way to to create a *new dictionary* and in any case it always requires a loop of sorts... And what do you mean by *efficiently*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475384/rename-a-dictionary-key)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {0: -1.0, 21: 2.23, 7: 7.1, 46: -12.0}

d = {f"p{k}":v for k,v in d.items()}

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'p0': -1.0, 'p21': 2.23, 'p7': 7.1, 'p46': -12.0}
```

---

---

---

*Note that this will work too:*

```
d = {f"p{k}":d[k] for k in d}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mention in the question of item assignment and `pop` suggests that you wish to modify the existing dictionary.  Unfortunately, you can only use the methods available, and there is no method to rename a key.  Rather than do repeated item assignment and pop, the other option is simply to clear the dictionary completely and `update` from a complete new dictionary containing the modified keys.  For example:

```
d1 = d.copy()
d.clear()
d.update({"p" + str(k): v for k, v in d1.items()})
```

Comment: string concatenation with the int to string conversion `"p" + str(k)` was slower than an f-string `f"p{k}"` when I tried it on my machine using python 3.8.3.