# Django to change form field error message

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with form errors. I want to change the field name that the form error displays.

## models.py

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer")
    ctype = models.ForeignKey("Customer_type", verbose_name="Customer Type")
```

## forms.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class Sales_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sales
        fields = ('customer','ctype')
        error_messages = {
            'ctype' : {
                'required' : _("Hey yow! this field is required!")
            }
        }
```

but the error still returns:

**{"ctype": ["Hey yow! this field is required!"]}**

What I want is like this

**{"Customer Type": ["Hey yow! this field is required!"]}**

http://pastebin.com/w6UkjzHF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify labels for fields in your `Meta` like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class Sales_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sales
        fields = ('customer','ctype')
        labels = {
            'ctype': _('Customer Type'),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'ctype' : {
                'required' : _("Hey yow! this field is required!")
            }
        }
```

AFAIK there's no direct way to use model field's verbose_name as form label. You can use `_meta` attribute though:

```
myfield = models.IntegerField(label=MyModel._meta.get_field('myfield').verbose_name)
```

Quite hacky in my taste because you still need to pass fieldname.

And you also can build labels dict with `dictionary comprehension`:

```
labels = {f.name: f.verbose_name for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()}
```

But be careful with this because `get_fields` also returns `ManyToManyRel` which has no attribute `verbose_name`.

You can refer to [render errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages) part of django docs also, might be helpful.

if you want just change keys in your form.errors dict, you can do this with this approach:

```
labels = {f.name: f.verbose_name for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()}
errors_keys = tuple(form.errors.keys())
for k in errors_keys:
    form.errors[labels[k]] = form.errors[k]
    del form.errors[k]
```

Or just `form.errors[labels[k]] = form.errors.pop(k)`.
Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4406501/3606603) question about dict key replacement

Comment: Thank you for the response @valen. I tried your answer but the labels doesn't seem to work and the error message is still the same.

Comment: May be I misunderstand your question a little bit. Do you want pretty verbose labels on html page or just replace key in errors dict?

Comment: Sorry for that. I just want to replace the key in erros dict.