# Update dictionary keys in a loop in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to update the keys of my dictionary `c` with its new keys `k_new`. Even though I am referring different stack overflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary) it does not get updated. Please tell me where I make it wrong.

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
c = {'apples': 3, 'biscuits and tea': 3, 'oranges and onions': 4}
for k in c:
    splits=k.split()
    k_new= " ".join(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in splits)
    c[k_new] = c.pop(k)
print(c)
```

PS: I also used:

```
c[k_new] = c[k]
del c[k]
```

Then I get `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Please help me

Comment: Noo... do not update a dictionary while you iterate over it...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You update the dictionary while you iterate over it:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
c = {'apples': 3, 'biscuits and tea': 3, 'oranges and onions': 4}
for k in c:  # iterate over c
    splits=k.split()
    k_new= " ".join(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in splits)
    c[k_new] = c.pop(k)  # update (two times) c
print(c)
```

updating a collection while you iterate over it is usually a very bad idea. Most data structures are not designed to handle this.

You can however *construct* a new dictionary:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
c = {'apples': 3, 'biscuits and tea': 3, 'oranges and onions': 4}
c_new = {}
for k in c:
    splits=k.split()
    k_new= " ".join(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in splits)
    c_new[k_new] = c[k]
print(c_new)
```

We can make this more elegant by using *dictionary comprehension*:

```
{" ".join(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in k.split()): v
 for k,v in c.items()}
```

this one-liner constructs a new dictionary where we iterate over key-value pairs `k,v` of `c`, and add a key `" ".join(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in k.split())` that we associate with the value `v`.

Comment: @thebjorn: yes. That is what I do in the list comprehension: I propose a fix, but then aim to show an - imho - more elegant way to do it.

Comment: both your solutions create new dicts, which is fine but not strictly necessary in this case since the OP can mutate his dict in place if he iterates over `c.items()` (or creates any other separate data structure to hold the keys).  Personally I think the dict comprehension is too complex in this case (and the `: v` almost disappears), but that's probably more of a taste issue..

Comment: @thebjorn: but then we will use memory to hold the keys. `c.items()` is an iterable as well, so this is not a solution either (gives the same error, in Python-3.x). Since `items()` is a proxy that iterates almost the same way over the dict, but takes the value in the dict as well into account.

Comment: that's a Py3 misfeature, in my world `c.items()` returns a list :-D  ps: you're holding two entire copies of the dictionary in memory, so the `c.items()` (py2) or `list(c)`don't consume any more memory..

Comment: @thebjorn: then how is the list maintained? It means a malloc to construct a list object, that has at least as size the size of a reference pointer times the number of items in it. Since one want the ammortized cost of an append to be *O(1)*, usually it can be as large as the next power of two.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over dictionary while it is changing might have weired effects since you are using a real-time reference to the keys. Just make a list out of the key view and it will work:

```
for k in list(c):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I want to get the values as well assigned for the keys while changing keys. Can we do it with lists?