# Modify dictionary in Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
DATA = {"records": [{"key1": "AAA", "key2": "BBB", "key3": "CCC", 
"key4": "AAA"}]}
```

I want to change "records" with for example "XX" so I will have the following:

```
DATA = {"XX": [{"key1": "AAA", "key2": "BBB", "key3": "CCC", "key4": 
"AAA"}]}
```

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Use: `DATA['XX'] = DATA.pop('records', None)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the name of a key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a string dictionary key directly in the way you have presented. The reason for this is that the key itself- which again, is a string, or `str` object- is immutable. This would not necessarily be true for other types of keys, such as for a user-defined object.

Your only option is to add the new key to the existing dictionary, or create a new dictionary with the key you want.

You can assign a new dictionary to the same name, `DATA`, and add the entry you want to the new dictionary (the old one will eventually be garbage collected):

```
DATA = {'XX': DATA['records']}
```

*IMPORTANT:* Note that any other references to the old `DATA` dictionary will NOT be updated! For this reason, the new dictionary approach is probably not what you want.

Alternatively, if it is acceptable to keep the `records` key in your dictionary, you can simply add the `XX` member to the dictionary and point it to the same value:

```
DATA['XX'] = DATA['records']
```

Lastly, if you both want to keep the original dictionary AND remove the `records` key from it, you will have to do that in two steps:

```
DATA['XX'] = DATA['records']
del DATA['records']
```

OR:

```
DATA['XX'] = DATA.pop('records')
```

Note that the last suggestion still occurs in two steps even though it is one line of code.