# How to replace a key in a list/Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list in that list dictionary is present how to replace key of that dictionary?

```
a = [{ 1:'1',2:'2',3:'3',4:'4',5:'5',1:'1'}]
for n, i in enumerate(a):
if i == 1:
   a[n] = 10
```

1 is a key have to replace with 10,so i have tried in above method but  can't able to do
the final thing i want is

```
a = [{ 10:'1',2:'2',3:'3',4:'4',5:'5',10:'1'}]
```

Comment: can you show what you'd have wanted the end result dictionary to look like?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in the dictionary, like you have here

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh no it doesn't. The OP wants to replace the _key_ not the value (I think they edited that in after you commented, actually)

Comment: Your expected output is _impossible_. You cannot have a dictionary with two keys that are both `10`. That said, the original is just as impossible for the same reason. It is a requirement that dictionaries have unique keys, so any entries with the key will just be overwritten. In this particular example, it's not an issue because both `1` or `10` keys have the same value stored against them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the name of a key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Original:

```
   a = [{ 1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,1:1}]
   for n, i in enumerate(a):
       if i == 1:
          a[n] = 10
```

First thing to know is, arrays start at 0. You have

```
if i == 1:
```

and so, your code will never execute.

You also have a duplicate key in your dictionary - 1 is used twice.

Since your dictionary is in a list, it will have to be index like:

```
a[i][j] = ...
```

where i refers to which element it is in the list, and j refers to which element in the dictionary.

Last, your i and n are reversed - enumerate puts the index in the first variable.

So, if I understand correctly what you want to accomplish, the end result should end up looking more like this:

```
a = [{1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5}]
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    if i == 0:
        a[0][1] = 10

print(a)
```

If you want to change the value for more than 1 key, then I might do something like this:

```
a = [{1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5}]
toChange = [[1,10], [4, 76]] # 1 and 4 are the keys, and 10 and 76 are the values to change them to
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    if i == 0:
        for change in toChange:
            a[0][change[0]] = change[1]

print(a)
```

EDIT: Everything above is still correct, but as you and Tomerikoo pointed out, it does not quite answer the question. My apologies. The following code should work.

```
a = [{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}]
toChange = [[1, 10], [4, 76]]  # 1 and 4 are the keys, and 10 and 76 are the 
values to change them to
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    if i == 0:
        for change in toChange:
            try:
                oldValue = a[0][change[0]]
                del a[0][change[0]]
                a[0][change[1]] = oldValue
            except:
                pass # handle it here
                #This likely means you tried to replace a key that isn't in there
print(a)
```

Comment: if n times have to replace then what to do

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you mean you want to replace the value for more than one key?

Comment: Have to change key not a value

Comment: 1) there is no correlation between *arrays start at 0* and the line `if i == 1:`. `i` in that case the whole dict itself. So this check will always be False. 2) your line `a[0][1] = 10` changes the value of the key `1`. OP wanted to change the key

Comment: try block in one line: `a[0][change[1]] = a[0].pop(change[0])`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `enumerate` here. Notice that the first key's value get's overwritten.

```
a = [{1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 1: '1'}]  # duplicate key
print(a)            # [{1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5'}]  (got overwritten)
a[0][10] = a[0][1]  # copy the value of the key 1 to the key 10
a[0].pop(1)         # remove the key 1
print(a)            # [{2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 10: '1'}]
```

Also, note that in the original example the indentation of the `if` block is wrong.

Comment: in one line: `a[0][10] = a[0].pop(1)`. `pop` deletes a key but returns its value

Comment: @Tomerikoo true