# How to overwrite 'int' key in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has a key containing a string and int data type:

```
{'Key1': 0, 0: True, 1: False, 2: None}
```

I want to overwrite the key value to this:

```
{'Key1': 0, -2: True, -1: False, 0: None}
```

How do I overwrite only the int key?

Comment: Or this? [Change the name of a key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4406501/7509065) (If a  Python gold badge user sees this, please add this as an additional dupe target)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Added. As a side note, you might consider revisiting the GoFundMe page in your profile.