# How to change the key value of a dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy

i got a large textfile (https://int-emb-word2vec-de-wiki.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/vectors.txt) and put the file into a dictionary:

```
word2vec = "./vectors.txt"

with open(word2vec, 'r') as f:
    file = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    model = {k: np.array(list(map(float, v))) for k, *v in file}
```

So i got this dictionary: `{Word: Embedding vectors}`.

Now I want to convert my key from: `b'Word'` to: `Word` (so that I got for example `UNK` instead of `b'UNK'`).

Does anyone know how I can remove the `b'...'` for every instance?
Or is it easier if i first remove all the `b'...'` in the textfile before I put the file into a dictionary?

Comment: Python3 usually does this by default. The output would be bytes, and I assume you're looking for str. Try dumping the dictionary into json using json.dumps().

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary/20563278 and also why dont just create the right key from first place

Comment: i am using Python 3.7

Comment: `model = {eval(k).decode(): np.array(list(map(float, v))) for k, *v in file}`

Comment: Is the key really `b'Word'`, or is it `"b'Word'"` (or `b'UNK'` versus `"b'UNK'"`, the word itself doesn't matter) ?

Comment: @martineau Thanks! That worked for me! ;)

Comment: Maxl: That's good to hear — you're welcome, however I suggest you use `ast.literal_eval(k)` instead of `eval(k)` because the latter is a security risk.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Now I want to convert my key from: `b'Word'` to: `Word` (so that I got for example `UNK` instead of `b'UNK'`).

The keys you get are strings like `"b'Word'"` and `"b'UNK'"`, **not** `b'Word'` and `b'UNK'`. Try executing `print(b"Word", type(b"Word"), "b'Word'", type("b'Word'"))`, it might make things clearer.

This should work:

```py
import ast
import csv

import numpy as np

with open("../out/out_file.txt") as file_in:
    reader = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter=" ")
    words = {ast.literal_eval(word).decode(): np.array(vect, dtype=np.float64) for word, *vect in reader}
```

This solution also appears to be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

why not just `str.decode()` it?

the line would be

```
model = {k.decode(): np.array(list(map(float, v))) for k, *v in file}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to change the Keys. You will need to add a new key with the modified value then remove the old one, or create a new dict with a dict comprehension or the like.