# How to replace existing key in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddict

So , I have this code.
I want to replace the specific existing key at index 1 in a dictionary in python.
Anyone have an idea on this?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
regDict= OrderedDict()
regDict[("glenn")] = 1
regDict[("elena")] = 2
print("dict",regDict)
```

prints:

```
dict OrderedDict([('glenn', 1), ('elena', 2)])
```

target output:

```
dict OrderedDict([('glenn', 1), ('new', 2)])  # replacing key in index 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the name of a key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach towards making a dictionary is a little bit off. Let's start by making a new dictionary from two lists (one for keys and one for values):

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
vals = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]

dictionary = {keys[i]:value for i, value in enumerate(vals)}
```

This gives us the following:

```
{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0}
```

You can also go here for some more help with making dictionaries: [Convert two lists into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

To replace the 'a' key with 'aa', we can do this:

```
new_key = 'aa'
old_key = 'a'

dictionary[new_key] = dictionary.pop(old_key)
```

Giving us:

```
{'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0, 'aa': 1.0}
```

**Other ways to make a dictionary:**

`dictionary = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}`

`dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))`

Where 'keys' and 'values' are both lists.

Comment: `dict(zip(keys,vals))`

Comment: ```zip()``` is wonderful and I agree completely - sometimes its easier to see where everything is going though. This is why I linked the other article.

Comment: don't teach people the elaborate way if there is a very clean simple way

Comment: I answered in a way that helped me learn dictionaries when I found many other things confusing. I am not claiming that the above is the most effective way at all (hence my link). Have added ```zip()``` to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad approach for a dictionary but a solution would look like below

```
index = len(regDict)-1
key = list(regDict.keys())[index]
value = regDict[key]
regDict["new"] = value
```

Note: This will only work if you want to change the last inserted key