# How to change the key values of dictionary from random numbers to consecutive integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like

```
dict1 = {1 : {'objects_1' : [1289,12678]} , 6 : {'objects_2' : [7798,808]} , 8 : ['object_2' : [76789,879]} }
```

Basically, the dict1.keys() are 1,6,8,10,15,...100 Is there a way to reassign these values with consecutive integers starting from 1,2,3,4,5..100

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: By "real numbers" do you mean consequtive integers?

Comment: You can check this answer and adapt it to your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406521/12569333

Comment: @bicarlsen YES, from randomly sorted (1,6,8,9..) to consecutive integers(1,2,3,4,..)

Comment: @RaghaviR You mean to sort the dictionary based on it's keys ?

Comment: @Ram No, it's already sorted but the keys are random numbers 1,3,5,6.. and I want to reassign with continuous numbers starting from 1,2,3,4.. consecutively

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a valid dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a New Dictionary and copy `dict1.values()` to it.

```
new_dict = {}

for key,value in enumerate(dict1.values(),1):
    new_dict[key] = value

# Output:
# new_dict = {1: {'objects_1': [1289, 12678]}, 2: {'objects_2': [7798, 808]}, 3: {'object_2': [76789, 879]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest recreating the dictionary using a dictionary comprehension along with `enumerate`.

```py
new_dict = { index: val for index, ( _, val ) in enumerate( old_dict.items() ) }
```

Comment: `dict(enumerate(dict1.items()))`

Comment: No need for an actual comprehension

Comment: Great point @MadPhysicist, I suggest posting this as you own answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a timing benefit to not using a comprehension.

Comment: Can you do the timing? I'm on mobile

Comment: Surprisingly, the comprehension seems to be slightly faster, but both increase linearly with dictionary size. [Plot](https://imgur.com/I9wYH27)

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do is to go over the dictionary items.
You can do that by iterating on `keys` with `keys()` method.

Then you could create an enumerator for each iteration. You can do that with `enumerate()`. `enumerate()` has its own value sequential starting from 0 if you do not declare anything or from a start parameter.

So for each iteration now you have the enumerate value and your key. You can assign a new key to your dictionary with the enum value as key, and as assigned value the result of the `pop()` method for the specific key you are each time.

Code example:

```
dict1 = {1 : {'objects_1' : [1289,12678]} , 6 : {'objects_2' : [7798,808]} , 8 : {'object_2' : [76789,879]} }

print(dict1)

for enum, i in enumerate(dict1.keys(), 1):
    print (enum, i)

    dict1[enum] = dict1.pop(i)

print(dict1)
```

EDIT based on Mad Physicist comment and thanks for reminding me

Comment: Enumerate takes a start argument

Comment: What if: `dict1 = {8 : {'objects_1' : [1289,12678]} , 6 : {'objects_2' : [7798,808]} , 1 : {'object_2' : [76789,879]} }`?

Comment: I do not think this is what he asks. It seems that it is just needed to assign keys in sequence.

Comment: The point I am making is that your algorithm requires that the dictionary you are processing already starts off with the keys in ascending sequence 1, 6, 8. It will fail when you iterate the input keys you get instead 8, 6, 1. That is, you are returned a key value (i.e. 1) for which you have *already* assigned a key value. Why don't you just *try* replacing `dict1` with the above declaration and see what I am talking about.

Comment: I guess you could just sort the keys in such cases. Still not in the question description tho.

Comment: @KarolosK. Correct! I already sorted it so no issues there, THANKS!

Comment: Being sorted doesn't necessarily help. What if the input keys were 0, 1, 2? That is sorted and it would still fail.

Comment: you could create a new dict and get the values there instead of replacing keys in the original dict.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use any explicit for-loops to achieve this. We can simply leverage `zip` and that it stops itself when one of two iterables is exhausted. We can create some arbitrarily large `range` as well since it is not all stored in memory either.

```
dict(zip(range(1, 1_000), dict1.values()))

{1: {'objects_1': [1289, 12678]},
 2: {'objects_2': [7798, 808]},
 3: {'object_2': [76789, 879]}}
```

Disclaimer: This will work as *expected* in Python 3.7+ as `dict`'s now preserve items in order of insertion. Otherwise we would have to use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Instead of 1000 use `len(dict1) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make any assumptions as to the insertion order of the keys, assuming you want to update the dictionary in place.

```py
dict1 = {8 : {'objects_1' : [1289,12678]} , 6 : {'objects_2' : [7798,808]} , 1 : {'object_2' : [76789,879]} }
old_keys = list(dict1.keys())
for idx in range(1, len(old_keys) + 1):
    if idx in old_keys:
        old_keys.remove(idx)
    else:
        old_key = old_keys.pop(0)
        dict1[idx] = dict1.pop(old_key)
print(dict1)
```

Prints:

```
{1: {'object_2': [76789, 879]}, 2: {'objects_1': [1289, 12678]}, 3: {'objects_2': [7798, 808]}}
```

Granted this *could* change the insertion order of the *values* but *will* handle any arbitrary input.

If you are running Python 3.7 (or CPython 3.6) or later where the assumption is that a `set` maintains insertion order and its `pop` method will remove items in insertion order, then you could use:

```py
dict1 = {0 : {'objects_1' : [1289,12678]} , 1 : {'objects_2' : [7798,808]} , 2 : {'object_2' : [76789,879]} }
old_keys = set(dict1.keys())
for idx in range(1, len(old_keys) + 1):
    if idx in old_keys:
        old_keys.remove(idx)
    else:
        old_key = old_keys.pop()
        dict1[idx] = dict1.pop(old_key)
print(dict1)
```