# Python modify dictionary names iterate

Tags: python

If I have a dictionary like this below:

```
test = {'1629417600000': {'Payload': 1},
         '1629418500000': {'Payload': 2},
         '1629419400000': {'Payload': 3},
         '1629420300000': {'Payload': 4},
         '1629421200000': {'Payload': 5},
         '1629422100000': {'Payload': 6},
         '1629423000000': {'Payload': 7},
         '1629423900000': {'Payload': 8},
         '1629424800000': {'Payload': 9},
         '1629425700000': {'Payload': 10}}
```

How can I modify the dictionary key names? I am trying to keep the same name but divide as a float by 1000.

This will throw an `RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration` below. Any tips greatly appreciated.

```
for key in test.keys():
    test[str((float(key)/1000))] = test.pop(key)
```

Comment: Don't try to modify the dictionary, just create a new one

Comment: Ad an aside, why involve floats here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the name of a key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary)

Comment: Its unix time. Maybe int is what I need not float. Would you have a tip on how to create a new dictionary?

Comment: When you iterating a list or dictionary, you can not change it, because your are iterating it. if you want to change anything such as key, you have to create a temp list of keys that you want to change. In your example, instead of pop. you have to save them in another list and after for loop ended, change items. good lock

Comment: Ah thanks. That makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary with the updated keys you desire:

```
test = {str(int(k) // 1000): v for k, v in test.items()}
```

Comment: You can slice 3 last chars from string instead of 
conversion `test = [k[:-3]: v for k, v in test.items()}`

Comment: Why not use a substring instead of double conversion

Comment: @Musa would work too, note, python doesn't have a `double` type. Only a single `int` type

Comment: I meant converting twice, string to int then int to string

Answer (score 3):

Try this?

```
test = {key.removesuffix("000"): value for key, value in test.items()}
```

However note that this does not modify `test` in-place, but rather creates a new dictionary, and then assign the new dictionary to `test`.

Alternatively, a minor change to your original code would fix it:

```
for key in list(test.keys()):
    test[str((float(key)/1000))] = test.pop(key)
```

This works because the `list(test.keys())`, that is being iterated, does not change during the iteration since it is created before the iteration starts and does not depend on the change of `test` later on.

Comment: You can just use `list(test)`

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
for key in list(test.keys()):

    test[str((float(key)/1000))] = test.pop(key)
```