# Python list of dictionaries - access keys

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

I need to change name of the keys in dictionary using item.replace(" ", "_").lower()
How could I access these keys?

```
{
  "environment": [
    {
      "Branch Branching": "97/97(100%)",
      "Test Status": "TC39",
    },
    {
      "Branch Branching": "36/36(100%)",
      "Test Status": "TC29",
    }
],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use:

```
dictionary[new_key] = dictionary.pop(old_key)
```

In your example:

```
env = {
    "environment": [
        {
            "Branch Coverage": "97/97(100%)",
            "Test Environment": "REGISTERHANDLING",
            "Test Configuration": "TC39",
        },
        {
            "Branch Coverage": "36/36(100%)",
            "Test Environment": "PRA",
            "Test Configuration": "TC29",
        }
    ],
}

# Looping over each index in the env['environment'] list, 
# this way we can edit the original dictionary.

# Note that enumerate returns a tuple of values (idx, val)
# And _ is commonly used to demonstrate that we will not be using val, only the index.
for index, _ in enumerate(env['environment']):

    # For each key, we want to create a new key and delete the old one.
    for key in env['environment'][index].keys():

        # Calculate the new key
        new_key = key.replace(" ", "_").lower()

        # .pop deletes the old key and returns the result, and the left hand side of this operation creates the new key in the correct index.
        env['environment'][index][new_key] = env['environment'][index].pop(key)
```

---

This question was already solved before, if you'd like to explore other answers, [click here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary)

Comment: I need to access keys Branch Coverage, Test Environment, Test Configuration. And by using for key in env["environment"].keys() I get this error:

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: @Irenaaa edited the answer accordingly. Please mark it as correct if it satisfies your question.