# How can we update parent header in json file using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

In the above JSON file, I have header names like `901`, `9x1` and `9x2`.

I want to change the header names like this:

- `9x1` to `911`
- `9x2` to `912`

I have tried following approach using python

```
tot = [911,912]
data = "above mentioned json file"
    for j in data:
        for i in tot:
           if j == '9x1':
             data[j][0] = i
```

The JSON file:

```json
{
  "901": [
    {
      "section": "Revision",
      "section": "Appendix A",
      "section": "Region Code",
      "Table": "Region",
      "Bundle": "1.0.0.9",
      "Software": "1.0.0.2",
      "iOS Simulator": "1.1.1.1",
      "Configuration": "1.0.0.1"
    }
  ],
  "9x1": [
    {
      "section": "Revision",
      "section": "Appendix A",
      "section": "Region Code ",
      "Table": "Region",
      "Bundle": "1.0.0.9",
      "Software": "1.0.0.2",
      "iOS Simulator": "1.1.1.1",
      "Configuration": "1.0.0.1"
    }
  ],
  "9x2": [
    {
      "section": "Revision",
      "section": "Appendix A",
      "section": "Region Code",
      "Table": "Region",
      "Bundle": "1.0.0.9",
      "Software": "1.0.0.2",
      "iOS Simulator": "1.1.1.1",
      "Configuration": "1.0.0.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the name of a key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary)

Comment: Perhaps not as i am keeping the values to change in a list and looking to change in json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work for you.

```
tot = [911,912]
data = "above mentioned json file"
for i in tot:
    if '9x1' in data:
        data[i] = data.pop('9x1')
```

Suggestion:

```
tot = {'9x1': 911, '9x2': 912}
data = "above mentioned json file"
for old_value, new_value in tot.items():
    if old_value in data:
        data[new_value] = data.pop(old_value)
```

Comment: thanks it worked when i have to change only for '9x1' how should i handle the case where i need to change multiple value i.e '9x2' with '912' , '9x3' with '913'

Comment: @UShukla Updated answer with the suggestion. I have updated `tot` to be a `dict` which will include all the old_values and new_values combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping dictionary and iterate over `data`, lookup the old key in `renameMapping`, if found the new key is used elsewise the old one:

```
renameMapping = {"9x1": "911", "9x2": "912"}
data = {renameMapping.get(oldKey, oldKey): v for oldKey, v in data.items()}
print(data.keys())
```

Out:

```
dict_keys(['901', '911', '912'])
```