# Replacing dictionary indices with specific names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Hi I have this dictionary

```
df = 
{
1: 0.03287410711253387, 
2: 0.1110746346378032, 
3: 0.23769202033121095, 
4: 0.6183592379186247
}
```

I'd like to replace the `1,2,3,4` with `A,B,C,D`

I have tried

```
df['A','B','C','D'] = df.pop[1,2,3,4]
```

it gives me this error

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 414 elements, new
> values have 4 elements

Comment: I am working with a large data frame, sorry I didn't write this question the right way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the name of a key in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it's tagged pandas but you can do:

```
dict(zip(['A','B','C','D'], df.values()))
```