# How to re-index a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I originally has a dictionary like the following:

```
mydict = {int(i): 'values' for i in range(5)}
{0: 'values', 1: 'values', 2: 'values', 3: 'values', 4: 'values'} # output
```

then i removed two of the index:

```
del mydict[0]
del mydict[3]
{1: 'values', 2: 'values', 4: 'values'} # output
```

And now i would like to "reindex" the dictionary into something like:

```
 {0: 'values', 1: 'values', 2: 'values'} # output
```

my real dictionary are much larger than this so it is not possible to do it manually..

Comment: a dictionary with integers as keys is a code smell. Are you sure you don't need a list instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```py
mydict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 4: 'd'}

mydict = dict(enumerate(mydict.values()))
print(mydict) # {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'd'}
```

Note that this is guaranteed only for python 3.7+. Before that, a dict is not required to preserve order.

If you do want to be safer, you can sort the items first:

```py
mydict = {2: 'b', 1: 'a', 4: 'd'}

mydict = dict(enumerate(v for _, v in sorted(mydict.items())))
print(mydict) # {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'd'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in another way using `zip` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493556/13394817)) at once. If:

```
dict_ = {1: 'values', 2: 'values', 4: 'values'}

d = dict(zip(range(3), list(dict_.values())))
# {0: 'values', 1: 'values', 2: 'values'}
```

Here, `range(3)` is the target list that will be as new *keys*.