# Check for either key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a the following code to get some messages from a telegram bot with python:

```
useful_messages = [i["message"] for i in response["result"] if i["message"]["from"]["id"] == int(chat_id) and i["message"]["date"] > last_time]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
KeyError: 'message'
```

`chat_id` is the id of the user I'm interested in, and `last_time` is used to avoid reading the whole chat with the user.

It worked for some months until today I hit an "edge case":

```
[i.keys() for i in response["result"]]

[dict_keys(['update_id', 'message']), 
 dict_keys(['update_id', 'message']), 
 dict_keys(['update_id', 'edited_message']), 
 dict_keys(['update_id', 'message'])]
```

As you can see, one of the messages was edited, and its key is no longer `message` but `edited_message`, causing the `KeyError` above.

I know I can use a for loop, check for either key (`message` or `edited_message`) and continue with the message validation (date and id) and extraction. **But I wondered if it is possible to check for either key in the dictionary**, thus keeping the list/dictionary comprehension (a one-liner solution would be ideal).

I also thought of replacing the `edited_message` key, if present, by following any of the procedures shown in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406501/change-the-name-of-a-key-in-dictionary). Sadly they are hardly one-liners, so the for loop seems to be a less verbose and convoluted solution.

**Of course, I'm open to any other solution (or programming logic)** that will result in better code.

I'm still new to python, so I'd appreciate your detailed explanations, if complex solutions are offered.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `response["result"]` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `python>=3.8` you can use the walrus operator

```
useful_messages = [x for i in response["result"]
                   if (x := i.get("message", i.get("edited_message")))["from"]["id"] == int(chat_id)
                   and x["date"] > last_time]
```

---

Without it would be less performant

You could do `i.get("message", i.get("edited_message"))` but keeping the list comprehension would mean repeat it 3 times instead of one, which isn't very performant (unless you don't have many items (not millions))

```
useful_messages = [i.get("message", i.get("edited_message")) for i in response["result"] 
                   if i.get("message", i.get("edited_message"))["from"]["id"] == int(chat_id) 
                   and i.get("message", i.get("edited_message"))["date"] > last_time]
```

---

A for loop would be cleaner then, a cleaner and performant code values more than a short code

```py
useful_messages = []

for i in response["result"]:
    msg = i.get("message")
    if msg is None:
        msg = i["edited_message"]

    if msg["from"]["id"] == int(chat_id) and msg["date"] > last_time:
        useful_messages.append(msg)
```

Comment: To store the value of `.get(..., ...)` within the comprehension without having to call it again, you could use a walrus operator, and replace the latter calls with the variable assigned to it. Obviously this only works if you have Python >= 3.8.

Comment: ```useful_messages = [x := i.get("message", i.get("edited_message")) for i in response["result"] 
                   if x["from"]["id"] == int(chat_id) 
                   and x["date"] > last_time]```

Comment: That is a good idea BUT that is not how it works, see my edit. The "if" part is executed before, if not you would evaluate the result part for items filtered, that would be poor performant

Answer (score 0):

for nested comprehension I like to separate lines, but you can one-line it if you don't care.

```
messages = [
    {'message': {'from': {'id': 1}, 'date': 'new'}},
    {'message': {'from': {'id': 1}, 'date': 'val'}},
    {'edited_message': {'from': {'id': 1}, 'date': 'new'}},
    {'edited_message': {'from': {'id': 1}, 'date': 'val'}},
    {'garbage': {'from': {'id': 1}, 'date': 'val'}},
    ]

useful_messages = [
    message[key]
    for message in messages
    for key in message
    if key in ('message', 'edited_message')
    and message[key]['from']['id'] == 1
    and message[key]['date'] == 'val'
    ]
```

output:

```
[{'from': {'id': 1}, 'date': 'val'}, {'from': {'id': 1}, 'date': 'val'}]
```